# Can I configure both Alt keys to print 3rd level signs via xmodmap or keyboard-options?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Currently only my right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (which `xev` prints out as `keycode 108 / "ISO-Level3-Shift"`) is able to print 3rd-level characters like `{[]}`. The left Alt key (`xev` shows it as `keycode 64 / Alt_L`) doesn't do anything, even though I set it via `xmodmap` like this:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = ISO_Level3-Shift"
```

This didn't work but (for some reason) made things even worse. After using the command, the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key stopped working printing these characters but produced a long sequence of what seems to be filenames, like this:

```
{.{7\ Wonders\ -\ Magical\ Mystery\ Tour,A{quaria,tomicWorm},Broken\ Rules,CrayonPhysicsDeluxe,F{BReader,ashionCents,ontmatr...
```

I also tried to use the option for "3rd level" in the keyboard-layout preferences, which didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did this:

use the `xev` command. This will allow you to get the decimal keycode of the key you want to choose as third-level chooser. Then close it.

Then calculate the hexadecimal number of the keycode you got and type the following :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 0xHEXA_NUMBER = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

Comment: `dc -e "DECIMAL_NUMBER 16 o p"` - will print the HEXA_NUMBER